# Potential offer BEFORE interview?

Tags: interviewing, recruiting

So long story short I had an interview set up, had an emergency and wasn’t able to reach out. Reached out a few days later and left a voicemail apologizing for the no show and explained ‘life happened’. I explained an emergency came up.

He called me two days later, was still interested and said if I was still looking for a job he wanted me to come in tomorrow to interview at 10 am. I accepted. He called me back 10 minutes later and said the manager wouldn’t be in until after noon, and said could we reschedule for Monday. I was hesitant but said yes. He then could feel my hesitance and asked “are you sure? If not we can reschedule” I explained I had an interview in another city tomorrow at 1 and it would work better to drop by after, however I was okay with Monday. He explained with check ins to the hotel, it would be difficult for Friday. (I’ve been in hotel forever and management for 2 years so I completely understood) he asked where I had an interview. I told him and he said someone he just hired came from there.

Turns out I’m interviewing for the position of someone they just hired. He said to ask if they would let me wait until Monday to accept or decline an offer if one is presented and said if they need an immediate answer, to please call him before I accept anything. He said “If they need an immediate answer call me first and we’ll see if we can work something out on the fly’

Should this be a red flag? While I know I have a lot of experience in hotel, this software they use is the only one I don’t know yet. What should I take from this?

Comment: Hello Katiedid243, and welcome to the Workplace. I've made some edits to help readability - if I've interfered with your intent, please feel free to roll back the changes, or let me know if you're unfamiliar with the site.

Comment: 1.) I would consider a demand for an immediate answer as a red flag. 2.) If you don't have an offer in writing you don't have it.

Comment: What is "hotel"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like he may truly be interested in interviewing you for the position. Something on your resume may have intrigued him enough to want a sit-down.

On the other hand, he may just be "blowing smoke". I'd be careful so that you don't end up without a job at either company.

Answer (score 5):

You need to be very careful.  Not having interviewed with the first company:

- you don't really know if they're a good fit for you.
- they don't really know if you're a good fit for them.

Their hiring manager sounds desperate if he would be willing to "work something out on the fly" rather than give a proper interview which could lead to him hiring you, realizing that you aren't a good fit, and releasing you shortly afterwards.

In any case, if you do receive an written offer for the second company and decide to "work something out on the fly" with the first company, do not settle for anything less than a written offer.

Comment: "work something out on the fly" could be a phone interview, for example.